# Spring dont see angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am trying adapt my app to use angular, but currently it seems that spring cannot see/communicate with angular. Here is what i have :

Controller.java:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
 public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getIndexPage() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello Worl123321");
    return model;
 } 
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <!--<link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>-->
      <style type="text/css">
        [ng\:cloak],
        [ng-cloak],
        .ng-cloak {
            display: none !important;
        }
      </style>
      <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>>
      <script src="app/app.js"></script>
      <script src="app/listView/listView.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
      <!-- Application content -->
      <div ng-include="'app/app.html'"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="appCtrl" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
        {{greeting.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/login/').success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
});
```

I just get an output like this :

> {"id":"01cdab29-e0ce-45ee-abb9-64b2640859ca","content":"Hello
>   Worl123321"}

and there seems that no angular scripts has been loaded...

Comment: Spring has nothing to do with loading Angular scripts.  Open the browser console and see what was loaded there.  That looks like a JSON object to me.  That's what the Spring controller was asked to create.  All is well.

Comment: I did this. No sources has been loaded, there is only output i show in first post.

Comment: That's what you asked Spring to do.  It's the JSON ResponseBody.

Comment: Where do you get the your output? And perhaps more important: where do you want the output? Because i don't see the 'greeting' attribute on your $scope being used in your view.

Comment: @duffymo Yes, but why i dont have any of may angular scripts?

ocket-san i edited with 'greeting' atribute

Comment: What URL do you exactly use in your browser?

Comment: @dunni my URL: http://localhost:8090/login

Comment: Ok, why are you calling the REST endpoint directly? Of course then the angular scripts are not loaded, since you don't load the index.html where the angular scripts are referenced. Just call localhost:8090 and your index.html together with your Angular scripts should load.

Comment: Ok, thanks for hrlp - i had routed url to localhost:8090/login and angular script cannot be loaded. My silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you use to serialise as JSON ?

This is maybe because of the Map<> that you have an extra field 'content' between  your object and your data try.

```
 $scope.greeting = data.content;
```

I've already heard of some problem like this with Jackson adding a "content" though it was for a hibernate problem.

If you don't want that extra field : create a wrapper class having an id and content field and use it.

Comment: i use jackson. The main problem for me is, that none of angular scripts are loaded, even if i remove map and will return only String.

Comment: so the output you quoted was the one from the server ?

Comment: if you open the developper tool, do you have any error ? I see thar yu include angular-bootstrap.js ? are you sure you're not missing a angular.js file before ? When you say angular doesn't seems to have loaded, what do you see in the html given by the tools provided by your broswer ? Is the ng-include still there ? Does your browser fired the request to load the app.html template ?

Comment: I don't have any error on developer tool. I include angular.js using webjars. In html is only text/json i get from server, nothing more, none of my scripts or html files are present. i dont see request for app.html

Comment: did you try to add a raw text in the app.html and see if it's displayed ?